# Beautiful soup missing data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using beautiful soup to try and scrape some financial information from a few different sites, but I'm noticing that most of the html information is missing from what I scrape. I have tried `html.parser`, `lxml`, and `html5lib` when parsing the scraped information without luck.

Below is a sample of the code I have been using with two different sites I have tried. In both examples I am trying to retrieve the market capitalization information, but I never seem to get it within my parsed output.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def get_marketcap(security):
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
    from urllib.request import urlopen

    loc = 'https://stockrow.com/AAPL'
    loc = 'https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=GOOGL+historical+market+capitalization+1.7.2018-1.10.2018'
    page = urlopen(loc)
    #soup = bs(page, 'html.parser')
    #soup = bs(page, 'lxml')
    soup = bs(page, 'html5lib')

    return soup, name_box


soup,name_box = get_marketcap('AAPL')
```

Comment: The data will most likely be added by JavaScript. Beautifulsoup can help you with then.

Comment: What is the point of re-defining `loc` variable? Also I don't see any elements with class `"neutralNumber"` on target page

Comment: It seems to be rendered by a javascript, I have had similar issues but managed to work around it with https://html.python-requests.org/. There is a `render` method that allows you to sleep and wait for the render to be finished.

Comment: @Andersson just trying to keep it easy to glance at, and yeah forget about the neutralNumber piece that was from a different site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you will be able to use the wonderful `requests-html` library (by the creator of requests) to grab elements that are rendered by JavaScript. You can adjust the sleep/wait time but the code below works for both your links and the full html content is returned.

```
def get_marketcap(url_path):
    from requests_html import HTMLSession
    session = HTMLSession()

    r = session.get(url_path)
    r.html.render(wait = 8, sleep = 8)

    return r.html

#url_path = 'https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=GOOGL+historical+market+capitalization+1.7.2018-1.10.2018'
url_path = 'https://stockrow.com/AAPL'
content = get_marketcap(url_path)
print(content.html)
```

Also note that it `requests-html` does not support iPython, the output can be saved in either a text file or you can print to view it.

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement this answer. I have installed nodejs and pyppeteer which both looks like they are necessary for this answer to work, but I am still getting a `sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'launch' was never awaited` error, and the script won't run. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running from an IDE and ran `pip install requests-html`, I should also add that according to the documentation it currently only supports Python 3.6

Comment: I am using 3.5.6 maybe that is causing the issue.

Comment: Yeah trying using a new `virtualenv` with Python 3.6X, glad to help if there are issues.

Comment: alright looks like everything works nicely with python 3.6.6 and requestshtml 0.9.0. Also seems to work okay in ipython too. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @BernardL , what is the point of creating Session if you want to make single request? This doesn't make sense

Comment: Well I just used the methods as described in the documentation, https://html.python-requests.org. If you are questioning the documentation, you can raise an issue. Also we are not using requests but requests-html.

Comment: Yeah, forgot that `requests-html` works not the same as `requests`

Answer (score 3):

Required data comes from XHR and you can get it with direct API request:

```
import requests

response_content =  requests.get('https://stockrow.com/api/companies/AAPL.json?ticker=AAPL').json()
print(response_content['prices'][0]['close'])
# 219.31
```

*UPDATE*

If you need values from the table (e.g. *Market Cap* value), you can use

```
response_content =  requests.get('https://stockrow.com/api/companies/AAPL/key_stats.json?ticker=AAPL').json()
print([item['value'] for item in response_content if item['indicator'] == "MARKETCAP:MRM"][0])
#  1077938914780.0000 # 1077938914780.0000 == 1,077,938.91m
```

In the same way you can extract other values like *Enterprise value* (key - `"EV:MRM"`), *Revenue* (key - `"REVENUE:MRT"`), etc... Just replace `"MARKETCAP:MRM"` key with appropriate one in the above code line

Comment: am I just completely missing how this applies to the market capitalization info I said I was looking for, because I don't see it in the example you provide.

Comment: @TheNightman , you didn't add desired output, so it was just an example of how you can get data. Check updated or specify which data exactly you need